# std::list splicing invalidates iterator

Tags: c++, iterator, splice

I've seen some posts about invalid iterators after splicing lists together but have not been able to find something to solve the issue.  I'm writing a routine

```
    for (KLUSTER::iterator iter = neighbours.begin(); iter != neighbours.end(); ++iter)
    {
        if (!(*iter).checked)
        {
            (*iter).checked = true;
            KLUSTER moreneighbours = T.RegionQuery(&(*iter), ClusterId);
            if (moreneighbours.size() >= DBS_MINPTS)
            {
                (*iter).ClId = *ClusterId;
                neighbours.splice(neighbours.end(), moreneighbours);    // ****
            }

        }
        if ((*iter).ClId == DBS_UNCLAS)
        {
            (*iter).ClId = *ClusterId;

            AddToCluster(cluster, &(*iter));
        }
    }
```

The splice line is marked // ****
If I comment this out, the loop stops.
If I don't comment this out, the loop doesn't stop.  Anybody know what I've gotten myself into please?

Thanks in advance.

P.S. I know how to get around it but I don't know whether I'm doing it right.

P.P.S. Forgot to add typedef std::list kluster; and #define KLUSTER kluster

Comment: Your iterators should remain valid according to the [`std::list splice` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/list/splice). Is it possible you keep adding data perpetually?

Comment: I must have screwed up somewhere.  Went back to the routine after a month and it was okay!  Anyway, dbscan is quite slow and I am evaluating other ways of clustering / segmentation.  Thanks for the advice!